# WATIR can't find links or buttons on parent when switching back from iframe

Tags: testing, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm on Ubuntu Linux/Firefox 13 and WATIR. (watir-webdriver-0.6.1)
I have a Webpage that contains links to about 16 iframes.. all linked like this....
Clicking "11" will bring up an iframe that has both a name and id equal to "page_11"

```
 <a href="javascript:nextPage(8);">9</a>
 <a href="javascript:nextPage(9);">10</a>
 <a href="javascript:nextPage(10);">11</a>
 <a href="javascript:nextPage(11);">12</a>
```

Clicking the number will put the iframe into the page and on the page is another box for comments (main page)

Here's what I ** DO ** know because I have verified it by the script. The page will come up showing all 16 links. I have my WATIR script to click the 11th link. It does that, it fills in the text boxes, it will then go back to the main page by using the browser.frame(:index,0).locate method and fill in the comments box which resides below the place where the iframes are filled in.

None of this is a problem.

The problem is trying to get the script to then click the link labeled "12". (It needs to go through these iframes sequentially)

It can't find the links on the main page again (or buttons for that matter). I end up with ....

```
[remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20120730-32067-1haylz3/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:5780:in `unknown': Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)
```

My script (the relevant parts) are below....

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require "webdriver-user-agent"
require 'headless'
require 'thread'

#Firefox 13 path below. Doesn't work with 14
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox.path = '/home/janie/Downloads/firefox/firefox'

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile.native_events = false;
browser=Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile

browser.goto("http://myurl/test")       
browser.link(:text,"11").click
browser.frame(:name,"page_11").locate
puts "Text fields "
puts browser.frame(:name,"page_11").text_fields.length

$counter=0
#This if loop works like a champ
if browser.frame(:id,"page_11").text_fields.length > 0
   puts "Found and iterating through Text Boxes"
   while $counter < browser.frame(:id, "page_11").text_fields.length do
       browser.frame(:id, "page_11").text_field(:index, $counter).set("Robot_Test")
   end
end

#Now go back to the main page
browser.frame(:index,0).locate

#The below works too so I know I am back on the top level/parent
if browser.text.include? "This is the main page"
  puts "--> Test Passed. Found the test string"
else
  puts "--> Test Failed! Could not find:"
end

#Now we are back in the main page again
browser.text_field(:name,"COMMENTS").set("ROBOT_TEST")
#The above works great

#And now the problem.....
browser.link(:text,"12").click
```

Kaboom! I get the can't find element error above.

For some reason, it no longer sees the links on the main page or buttons. Any idea what could be causing this? I have been searching for this all day and this about the ONLY thing left before I can run this script everything else works great.

Does anyone know how to get around this behavior in Watir?
Many thanks!
Janie

PS - I tried testing in Chrome and I get ..

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok': Element must be displayed to click (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)
```

Just thought I'd add.

The HTML is pretty massive so I'm trying to be as concise as possible.

**NOTE, more troubleshooting:**..... apparently the problem seems to be the script just doesn't successfully make the jump back to the parent frame index:0

Script modifications...

```
puts "Javascript links in page"
puts browser.links(:text, /^\d+$/).length
```

Javascript links in page
15
(correct)

```
puts "Link attribute of index:3"
puts browser.link(:index,3).text
```

Link attribute of index:3 
2
(correct)

```
browser.link(:text,"2").click
```

(Yep, works fine)

```
#Refocus just to be safe 
browser.frame(:index,0).locate
```

(The above line is pointless. Focus and refocus back to frame:index:0 makes no difference)

```
#We're supposed to be back in parent. Let's check the no. of links again
puts "Javascript links in page - after"
puts browser.links(:text, /^\d+$/).length
```

Javascript links in page - after
15
(Which makes me think that everything is ok)

```
puts "Link attribute of index:3"
puts browser.link(:index,3).text
```

should return "2" as above, but no value and the error message below.....

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.5.8/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:365:in `assert_exists': unable to locate element, using {:text=>"3", :tag_name=>"a"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.5.8/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:95:in `click'
```

**Note 2: Even more basic**:

```
   puts "Clicking link 2"
   browser.link(:text,"2").click
```

No problem

```
   puts "Clicking link 3"
   browser.link(:text,"3").click
```

Error

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok': Element must be displayed to click (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)
```

Comment: I can't replicate this.  Could we get some (basic) HTML that has this issue?

Comment: I'm sure it's probably something simple, but I'm going to have to use Perl's WWW::Mechanize until I can figure out what the problem is.If I come up with a solution, I'll repost.

Comment: Are the page links in the main part of the page or in another frame? From your code, it looks like your 'main page' is the first frame.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a bug within Watir-Webdriver, not entirely sure without html to reproduce it, but you could give the following a try (just before you try to click the 12 link):

```
browser.window(:url => the_url_of_your_page).use
```

It might 'refresh' the HTML of your page if something has messed up internally with Watir-Webdriver.  You never know!

Other than that I would have a look with something like Firebug to see if there's something different about the page after you click the link that makes the first iFrame appear.

If nothing has changed, ensure you can initially click the 12th page before any other actions.  If the error you're getting is correct, it's possible that there's a hidden element on the page with the same text as the link you're trying to select, in this case 12.  To ensure that isnt the case you can always use  `p links(:text => "12").count` to return the number of links with that text on the page.

Other than that I'm really not sure.

Comment: I'll look into this anonygoose. I added more above. (I'd give you points on your name alone. LOL!)

Comment: heh thanks.  Do you know if frame.locate is having any effect on your scripts at all?  When I tried using locate earlier it did nothing, and I could only access elements in an iFrame using e.g. browser.frame(:name => name).link(:text => "12").click

Comment: That seems to be the problem. I added another test in my original question above and apparently issuing a browser.frame(:index,0).locate does absolutely nothing as far as focusing back to the parent. This super blows because this is the ONLY problem holding up my test script. :-(

Comment: This is so weird.  I'm now having the problem you're encountering, I think.

If i first do browser.frame(:name => name).links.count I get the links inside the frame.  If I then do browser.links.count I get the links inside the frame too.  If I do browser.frame.locate inbetween it will give me the links for the main page the 2nd time.

I can still interact with the link on the main page, it simply isn't being returned if I use browser.links

Comment: Put an even more basic example in my original question. Apparently just the simple act of clicking a link to an iframe works and subsequent clicks to other iframes result in an error.